# while loop that reads value and checks for 2 possible answer - bash/centOS

Tags: bash, validation, while-loop, centos

I am having issues with this while loop where I am trying to check if the 'choice' value read from the user's input is NOT EQUAL to either 'yes' or 'false'. Right now the validation catches anything that isn't 'yes' or 'no'.

The **problem** is that, the validation ALSO enters the while loop when the user enters 'yes' or 'no'...

Does anyone have any idea about what is going on and how I could make this thing work?

```
while read choice && ([[ "$choice" != "yes" ]] || [[ "$choice" != "no" ]]); do
        echo -n "'$choice' is invalid choice, enter 'yes' or 'no': ";
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `([[ "$choice" != "yes" ]]` **&&** `[[ "$choice" != "no" ]])`

```
while read choice && ([[ "$choice" != "yes" ]] && [[ "$choice" != "no" ]]); do
    echo -n "'$choice' is invalid choice, enter 'yes' or 'no': ";
done
```

Comment: Oh god, I should've noticed that hahaha.
Thanks nonetheless @alnet!